# Is this really a removable singularity?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, partial-differential-equations

I was reading on partial differential equations using Laplace transforms, and the following function
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}\left(x - \frac{L\sinh(x \sqrt{z}) }{\sinh(L \sqrt{z} )} \right)$$
Had a removable singularity at z=0. However, since it was about the PDES and not the complex analysis part, I couldn’t understand why that is the case. Could someone show why ?
Also, here is the paper where I saw it, at page 5.
[https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~dtrim/BooksandNotes/Complex/ComplexPDEs.pdf](https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Edtrim/BooksandNotes/Complex/ComplexPDEs.pdf)

Comment: Well, first of all, you can use the power series for $\sinh(w)$ to get rid of the bigger problem, which is that $\sqrt w$ is not even defined and continuous in a complex neighborhood of $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Using $$\sinh (w)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{w^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$ you get:

$$f(z)=\frac{L\sinh(x\sqrt z)}{\sinh(L\sqrt z)}=\dfrac{x\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x^2z)^{k}}{(2k+1)!}}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(L^2z)^{k}}{(2k+1)!}}$$

We've gotten rid of the first problem, which is the $\sqrt z,$ which is not even continuous on a neighborhood of $0.$

Since the numerator and denominator are analytic, and the denominator is $1$ at $z=0,$ then $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $0.$ But we easily see $f(0)=x,$ so you want $\frac{f(0)-f(z)}z$ to have a removable singularity.

But if $f$ is any function analytic in a neighborhood of $0$, then $\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0.$ You can see this by just writing out the power series for $f.$

You can replace $\sinh(w)$ with  any odd function $g(w)$ analytic in a neighborhood of $0$ with $g'(0)\neq 0.$